# ionic2 - Application Error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.1
Node Version: v6.9.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

This is an Ionic 2 app, worked fine till recently. After upgrading to ionic framework Rc3 , during builds it throws an Error

```
-Application Error 
connection to the server was unsuccessful. File://android_asset/www/index.html
```

Tried reinstalling android platform and all.

But nothing seems to work on even a basic app.

Config.xml file contains

```
 <description>An  Ionic 2 Starter app.</description>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
```

......

I have tried the starter templates of ionic 2 and its the same result across 2 different linux machines and windows machine too. Interestingly it works fine in the android emulator, however fails on the mobile devices.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you try removing ``www`` folder?

Comment: Yep tried that too....the bug continues to live.

Comment: I have tried downgrading the ionic app-scripts to 0.0.46 and 0.0.47, still no luck.

Comment: Tried using starter templates that Ionic 2 provides - same error. So I can presume its an issue with the Ionic2 platform. Get the same error for Rc4 framework too.

Comment: I upgraded the ionic app-scripts to 1.0.0, it works fine in the emulator. However on the device a timeout error - deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds shows up.

Comment: I have tried the starter templates of ionic 2 and its the same result across 2 different opensuse linux machines and windows 8 machine too.  Boggles the mind, when they work fine in the emulator and fail on  the device.

Answer (score 2):

OK i have managed to get this working, downgrade the ionic-apps-scripts to 0.0.47. Add the cordova-device-plugin and finally to avoid timeout issues add this line in the preferences section in config.xml -

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```